# Dealing with errors while parsing strings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm tasked with pulling relevent data out of a field which is essentially free text.  I have been able to get the information I need 98% of the time by looking for keywords and using CASE statements to break the field down into 5 different fields.

My issue is I can't get around the last 2% because the errors don't follow any logical order - they are mostly misspellings.

I could bypass the field with a TRY CATCH, but I don't like giving up 4 good pieces of data when the routine is choking on one.

Is there any way to handle blanket errors within a CASE statement, or is there another option?

Current code, the 'b' with the commented out section is where it's choking right now:

```
CASE WHEN @Location = 0 THEN 
        CASE WHEN @Duration = 0 THEN 
            CASE WHEN @Timing = 0 THEN
                    SUBSTRING(@Comment,@Begin, @Context-@Begin)
                ELSE
                    SUBSTRING(@Comment,@Begin, @Timing-@Begin)
                END
            ELSE SUBSTRING(@Comment,@Begin, @Duration-@Begin)
            END
        ELSE SUBSTRING(@Comment,@Begin, @Location-@Begin)
    END AS Complaint
,CASE WHEN @Location = 0 THEN ''
    ELSE    
        CASE WHEN @Duration = 0 THEN 
            CASE WHEN @Timing = 0 THEN SUBSTRING(@Comment,@Location+10, (@CntBegin-11))
                ELSE SUBSTRING(@Comment,@Location+10, @Timing-(@Location+10))
            END
        ELSE SUBSTRING(@Comment,@Location+10, @Duration-(@Location+10))
        END
    END  AS Location
,CASE WHEN @Timing = 0 THEN ''
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN @CntBegin = 0 THEN
            SUBSTRING(@Comment,@Timing+@TimingEnd, (@Location+@Context)-(@Timing+@TimingEnd))
        ELSE
            'b'--SUBSTRING(@Comment,@Timing+@TimingEnd, (@Location+@CntBegin-1)-(@Timing+@TimingEnd))
        END
    END AS Timing
```

On this statement, which has a comma in an odd spot.  I have to reference the comma usually for the @CntBegin, but in this case it's making my (@Location+@CntBegin-1) shorter then the (@Timing+@TimingEnd):

'Pt also presents with/for mild check MGP/MGD located in OU, since 12/2015 ? Stability.'

Please take into account, I'm not necessarily trying to fix this error, I'm looking for a way to handle any error that comes up as who knows what someone is going to type.  I'd like to just display 'ERR' in that particular field when the code runs into something it can't handle.  I just don't want the routine to die.

Comment: Please give some examples of good data, corrupted data, your existing code and what you hope to achieve.

Comment: Perhaps you need `TRY_CAST` and/or `TRY_CONVERT`

Comment: Code and example added.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your error is due to the length parameter in SUBSTRING being less than 0. I always alias my parameters using CROSS APPLY and then validate the input before calling SUBSTRING(). Something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CA.StringLen > 0 /*Ensure valid length*/
    THEN SUBSTRING(@comment,@Timing+@TimingEnd,CA.StringLen)
    ELSE 'Error'
END
FROM YourTable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT StringLen = (@Location+@CntBegin-1)-(@Timing+@TimingEnd)) AS CA
```

Comment: That would work for this error.  What I'm attempting is something that will handle any other error that occurs which I haven't accounted for, since this is a templated free text field.  There's no way I'm going to be able to foresee every mistake that will be entered in this field.

Comment: What do you mean any other error? Like actual errors or incorrect parsing results?